# psql environment variables same as shell ones?

Tags: postgresql, psql

(I suspect the answer is yes, but I don't see it confirmed anywhere.)

In psql we can set environment variables using the `\setenv {name} {value}` command.

Are these the same environment variables as the ones in the shell?

---

For reference [the relevant page in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `\setenv` just calls the C library function `setenv()`. This changes the environment settings *of the `psql` process* and has no effect outside of that.

Comment: So what happens to an environment variable when we exit a psql session in which it was changed?

Comment: It disappears along with the process.